# Plotly notebook mode with google colaboratory

Tags: plotly, google-colaboratory

I am am trying out colaboratory with plotly notebook mode - I open a new notebook, copy and paste the following simple example from plotly's documentation, but don't see an output. There is a large blank in the output space where the plot whould normally be.

This works fine in my local notebook (which is a newer version of plotly, but per their docs offline mode should work with the google colab version)
Any ideas?

```
import plotly
from plotly.graph_objs import Scatter, Layout

plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

plotly.offline.iplot({
    "data": [Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3, 4], y=[4, 3, 2, 1])],
    "layout": Layout(title="hello world")
})
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

## `plotly` version 4.x

As of version 4, `plotly` renderers know about Colab, so the following is sufficient to display a figure in both Colab and Jupyter (and other notebooks like Kaggle, Azure, nteract):

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure( go.Scatter(x=[1,2,3], y=[1,3,2] ) )
fig.show()
```

## `plotly` version 3.x

Here's an example showing the use of Plotly in Colab. (Plotly requires custom initialization.)

https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=14oudHx5e5r7hm1QcbZ24FVHXgVPD0k8f

You need to define this function:

```
def configure_plotly_browser_state():
  import IPython
  display(IPython.core.display.HTML('''
        <script src="/static/components/requirejs/require.js"></script>
        <script>
          requirejs.config({
            paths: {
              base: '/static/base',
              plotly: 'https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js?noext',
            },
          });
        </script>
        '''))
```

And call it in each offline plotting cell:

```
configure_plotly_browser_state()
```

Comment: Thanks! It appears that `configure_plotly_browser_state()` needs to be called in every cell where I want to include a plot - is that correct? Do you know if its possible to initialize for the entire notebook?

Comment: Plotly does indeed need to be initialized for each cell. In Colab, each cell is rendered in an `iframe` sandbox, so there's no shared initialization state between outputs.

Comment: I added the function itself to the answer. Note also that you need to reference `plotly-latest.min.js` rather than `plotly-1.5.1.min.js` as is in the notebook.

Comment: `plotly` wasn't working for me even with version 4.6.0, so I had to resort to use  Pratik Parmar's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54771665/4332585)

Comment: Even on plotly version 4.x, there is need to call the initialization function in each cell. However, @Remis Haroon - رامز solution works well indeed.

Answer (score 48):

simply pass `"colab"` as the value for the parameter `renderer` in `fig.show(renderer="colab")`

example :

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure(
    data=[go.Bar(y=[2, 1, 3])],
    layout_title_text="A Figure Displayed with the 'colab' Renderer"
)
fig.show(renderer="colab")
```

[image]

Comment: This solution works on plotly version 4.x

Answer (score 27):

Solution

```
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default = "colab"
```

You need to change the default render. Here is an excerpt from the documentation.
https://plot.ly/python/renderers/#setting-the-default-renderer

> The current and available renderers are configured using the
> `plotly.io.renderers` configuration object. Display this object to see
> the current default renderer and the list of all available renderers.

```
>>>import plotly.io as pio
>>>pio.renderers


Renderers configuration
    -----------------------
        Default renderer: 'notebook_connected'
        Available renderers:
            ['plotly_mimetype', 'jupyterlab', 'nteract', 'vscode',
             'notebook', 'notebook_connected', 'kaggle', 'azure', 'colab',
             'cocalc', 'databricks', 'json', 'png', 'jpeg', 'jpg', 'svg',
             'pdf', 'browser', 'firefox', 'chrome', 'chromium', 'iframe',
             'iframe_connected', 'sphinx_gallery']
```

Answer (score 18):

You need to add a method in order to use Plotly in Colab.

```
def enable_plotly_in_cell():
  import IPython
  from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode
  display(IPython.core.display.HTML('''<script src="/static/components/requirejs/require.js"></script>'''))
  init_notebook_mode(connected=False)
```

This method must be executed for every cell which is displaying a Plotly graph.

Sample:

```
from plotly.offline import iplot
import plotly.graph_objs as go

enable_plotly_in_cell()

data = [
    go.Contour(
        z=[[10, 10.625, 12.5, 15.625, 20],
           [5.625, 6.25, 8.125, 11.25, 15.625],
           [2.5, 3.125, 5., 8.125, 12.5],
           [0.625, 1.25, 3.125, 6.25, 10.625],
           [0, 0.625, 2.5, 5.625, 10]]
    )
]
iplot(data)
```

Reference: https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/charts.ipynb#scrollTo=WWbPMtDkO4xg

Comment: This is excellent. Having tried all other solutions, this is the only one that worked. Great job, and thanks for finding and posting it.

Answer (score 15):

`configure_plotly_browser_state()` can be executed before running every cell by using IPython's pre_run_cell hook:

```
import IPython

IPython.get_ipython().events.register('pre_run_cell', configure_plotly_browser_state)
```

Comment: I get this: > Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-ac1874a09e95> in <module>()
      1 import IPython
----> 2 IPython.get_ipython().events.unregister('pre_run_cell', configure_plotly_browser_state)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/events.py in unregister(self, event, function)
     62     def unregister(self, event, function):
     63         """Remove a callback from the given event."""
---> 64         self.callbacks[event].remove(function)
     65 
     66     def trigger(self, event, *args, **kwargs):

ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

Comment: It gets elegant when you wrap over plotly's API where you conditionally initialize for colab when running on the colab runtime is detected (`get_ipython().__class__.__module__ == "google.colab._shell"`) and not otherwise.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `register` call?