# Ipywidgets with Google Colaboratory

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets, google-colaboratory

I am trying to use ipywidgets with Google Colaboratory, and (as with [plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47230817/plotly-notebook-mode-with-google-colaboratory)) the simplest [example from the docs](http://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Using%20Interact.html) does not work. The code below shows a slider in a local notebook but only returns 10 and `<function __main__.f>` in a Google notebook.

```
!pip install ipywidgets

from ipywidgets import interact

def f(x):
  return x

interact(f, x=10)
```

Is there another custom initialization that I could use to enable the widgets?

Comment: Hello, Have you found some solution? I have the same problem

Comment: Unfortunately no solution yet :(

Comment: I found how to enable the nbextension, but still not working 
`!pip install widgetsnbextension

!jupyter nbextension install --debug /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/widgetsnbextension

!jupyter nbextension enable --debug /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/widgetsnbextension

!jupyter nbextension list`

Comment: @AlejandroQH probably, somehow, the Jupyter server has to be restarted after installation/enabling of the module.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Update 2**: core `ipywidgets` now work in Colab, as do many custom widgets! In particular, the base, controls, FileUpload, Image, and output widgets all work in colab. See https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/498 for more details.

(Tweaked original answer): `ipywidgets` don't Just Work with Colab: we have a different security model, wherein each output is in its own iframe (with a different origin than the main Colab page). This prevents ipywidgets from working without changes on the Colab side.

Comment: Any plans to add this in the future?

Comment: https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/60 is the issue to follow and thumbs up.

Comment: Anyone used the Image widget, I tried the simple code given in the doc but the cell doesn’t show anything after execution.

Comment: Current github issue to track is: [#498](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/498#issuecomment-956321234)

Answer (score 3):

```
!pip install ipywidgets

# this will allow the notebook to reload/refresh automatically within the runtime
%reload_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2

from ipywidgets import interact

def f(x):
  return x

interact(f, x=10)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think now Ipywidgets is working with Google Collaboratory. I tested some decorators and it ran smoothly.

Your code has resulted in:

[image]

Comment: @dasilvadaniel It is still not working for me, the cell is run, but there is no plot displayed. When I type `!jupyter --version` I get the output:  `jupyter core     : 4.5.0
jupyter-notebook : 5.2.2
qtconsole        : 4.5.2
ipython          : 5.5.0
ipykernel        : 4.6.1
jupyter client   : 5.3.1
jupyter lab      : not installed
nbconvert        : 5.5.0
ipywidgets       : 7.5.0
nbformat         : 4.4.0
traitlets        : 4.3.2 `.  What are your configurations?

Comment: I'm afraid to say that I have the same settings as yours: 

jupyter core     : 4.5.0
jupyter-notebook : 5.2.2
qtconsole        : 4.5.2
ipython          : 5.5.0
ipykernel        : 4.6.1
jupyter client   : 5.3.1
jupyter lab      : not installed
nbconvert        : 5.5.0
ipywidgets       : 7.5.0
nbformat         : 4.4.0
traitlets        : 4.3.2

My runtime time is Python3. Could you check that? Maybe there is something with your cookies or something else related to your browser?

Answer (score 1):

As of 2021-12 the ipywidgets (widgets) work perfectly in Colab. Well, maybe not 100% of them but a pretty decent amount.

All you need is to import them (in whatever way you prefer, 2 examples below)

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import interact, interactive, fixed
```

And use (simple example)

```
widgets.Select(
    options=['Linux', 'Windows', 'macOS'],
    value='macOS',
    # rows=10,
    description='OS:',
    disabled=False
)
```

[image]

You have fantastic documentation here https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io

Answer (score 0):

`ipywidgets` are kinda-supported in colab now; a notable exception is `ipywidgets.Image`. See https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/587.

Comment: Yeah, image not working is a set back for me as I am trying to build some simple image labeler to assist manual labeling of images to construct a new dataset