# Interactive matplotlib figures in Google Colab

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, google-colaboratory, plotly-python

Normally in a jupyter notebook I would use `%matplotlib notebook` magic to display an interactive window, however this doesn't seem to work with google colab. Is there a solution, or is it not possible to display interactive windows in google colab?

Comment: I found this [issue](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/86). if you look at the last comment in the issue, you will see that only supported matplotlib backend is `inline`. The reason is x-forwarding requirement.

Comment: This makes sense, thanks for the link.  I've been using mybinder.org instead of google colab for most purposes requiring plotting.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Below is an example of creating interactive `iplot()` in Plotly and `cufflinks()` on Google Colab Notebook. Used functions and suggestions from the answer [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47230817/plotly-notebook-mode-with-google-colaboratory), [2]](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/14oudHx5e5r7hm1QcbZ24FVHXgVPD0k8f)

The key seems to be to include `configure_plotly_browser_state()` in the cell that does the plotting.

Code below should work:

**Import libraries**

```
import datetime
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from plotly import __version__
%matplotlib inline

import plotly.offline as pyo
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import iplot

import cufflinks as cf
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot 


cf.go_offline()
```

**Set notebook to false**

```
init_notebook_mode(connected=False)
```

**Create function for Colab**
copied from:  [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47230817/plotly-notebook-mode-with-google-colaboratory), [2]](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/14oudHx5e5r7hm1QcbZ24FVHXgVPD0k8f)

```
def configure_plotly_browser_state():
  import IPython
  display(IPython.core.display.HTML('''
        <script src="/static/components/requirejs/require.js"></script>
        <script>
          requirejs.config({
            paths: {
              base: '/static/base',
              plotly: 'https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js?noext',
            },
          });
        </script>
        '''))
```

Note: using `plotly: 'https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js?noext'`ensures the latest version of Plotly will be used. It is also possible to specify the version of plotly, by using e.g. `plotly: 'https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-1.5.1.min.js?noext'`.

**Create sample dataframe**

Data source: Annual rainfuall data for the Peachtree City, GA from National Weather Service [[3]](https://www.weather.gov/ffc/rainfall_scorecard).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'month': ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
    'Year_2018': [3.26, 6.11, 4.86, 6.53, 4.45, 3.86, 8.04, 7.59, 1.48, 4.75, 7.27, 11.83],
    'Year_1996': [8.26, 3.82, 6.42, 2.91, 2.12, 1.70, 2.14, 4.66, 4.32, 0.89, 3.22, 4.14]
}
)
df
```

**Create an interactive iplot**

```
configure_plotly_browser_state()
df.iplot(kind='line',x='month',y=['Year_2018', 'Year_1996'], color=['white', 'gold'], 
theme='solar', mode='markers+lines',title='Annual Rainfall in the city Peachtree City, GA')
```

Output:
[image: Output]

Comment: Do you know why the proper titles doesn't show up, instead saying "[Object Object]"?

Comment: copied into
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1tXS-kwZUWgkJqYXKxglg67yGQmenSl8d
for your convenience

Comment: I'm frustrated to have to use plotly rather than matplotlib, but this does more or less achieve the desired functionality so I will accept!

Comment: `matplotlib` can also be used in Jupyter notebooks, but it's not interactive, whereas `plotly` is.

Answer (score 9):

Facing the same issue (and after a lot of reading), I could not get `%matplotlib ipympl/widget` magic to work with Colab. However the next best solution is indeed to use Plotly, as outlined by @Nilesh Ingle in his detailed reply.

There is however a much simpler way to get Plotly up-and-running in Colab.

Please see this [shared Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1uVAuE_s6-tqM4E1B4aCiO1NtHyQgyF_m?usp=sharing) for a minimum example.

Python code also copied below for quick reference:

```
!pip install plotly

import plotly.express as px

SHEET_ID = '153pKW5IZRHwx9mLu_uU-hDSK0D3R19vR71EcgMYHn3I'

df = pd.read_csv('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + SHEET_ID + '/export?format=csv')

fig = px.scatter(data_frame=df, x="x", y="y", width=1000, height=800)
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be a backend issue. In jupyter notebooks, the command to list the different types of backends is:

```
%matplotlib --list
```

Output:

```
Available matplotlib backends: ['tk', 'gtk', 'gtk3', 'wx', 'qt4', 'qt5', 'qt', 'osx', 'nbagg', 'notebook', 'agg', 'svg', 'pdf', 'ps', 'inline', 'ipympl', 'widget']
```

However, for my system/setup, only 'notebook' and one other works. In jupyter labs, for me, none of the backends work for interactive graphs (even the 'inline' which is what they recommend).

Hope it reduces the hours of searches and permutations of install/re-installs that I went through  :))

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Nilesh Ingle excellent answer, in order to solve the problem of axes and title not displaying :
you should change the link `https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-1.5.1.min.js?noext` (which refers to an older version of plotly, thus not displaying axes labels) by `https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-1.5.1.min.js?noext` when calling the script in the function `configure_plotly_browser_state()`.
Hope this would help !

Answer (score 1):

A small correction to Nilesh Ingle's brilliant answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55435199/13705497

To eliminate the problem of axes and title not displaying - you can change the link https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-1.5.1.min.js?noext (this link is the culprit) to https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js?noext 
in the function configure_plotly_browser_state(). Have a great day!

Comment: Why is this a solution? Is there a bug in 1.5.1? Maybe a better suggestion would be to pinpoint the specific version where this bug was fixed?

Comment: @Glitcher Is relying on specific versions a good idea? Isn't using plotly-latest abstracting away from the user the need to decide on a proper version, and thus making things easier in the process? Would love to hear your thoughts on this.

Comment: Granted I don't know the environment this is being run in, but for many places updating a library is something you should only do if you need the new features or fixes that come with that update. This is because there's an inherent risk in updating a library; it could introduce bugs, or breaking changes that may not be accounted for.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution to get interactive matplotlib figure :

Support for third party widgets (widgets outside of the ipywidgets package) needs to be enabled separately. Support for these widgets will be loaded from a CDN external from Colab.

```
from google.colab import output
output.enable_custom_widget_manager()
```

Support for third party widgets will remain active for the duration of the session. To disable support:

```
from google.colab import output
output.disable_custom_widget_manager()
```

Here an exemple :

```
from google.colab import output
output.enable_custom_widget_manager()
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

fig = plt.figure()

# syntax for 3-D projection
axe = plt.gca(projection ='3d')

# Make data.
x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 200)
y = np.linspace(-5, 5, 200)

X,Y = np.meshgrid(x, y) 

# compute f(X,Y)
z = np.sin(np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2))

axe.plot_surface(X, Y, z, cmap=plt.get_cmap("coolwarm"))

# Customize the z axis size.
axe.set_zlim(-1, 1)
```

Comment: It's hard to determine how this answers the question. Can you include a complete example of how one would use this?

Comment: Hi @Aleks ,
I have added an example, let me know what you think ...

Comment: For this solution to work, it seems you need to add `!pip install ipympl` and `%matplotlib widget`, as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70482960/9987623) answer.

Answer (score 0):

From : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47230966/4106458 and combining this with the `asFigure` parameter mentioned in the help message of `iplot` at : https://github.com/santosjorge/cufflinks/blob/master/Cufflinks%20Tutorial%20-%20Plotly.ipynb

We can use the following code to render interactive Plotly graphs on Google Colab

```
import cufflinks as cf
(dataset[column]
  .iplot(kind="box", asFigure=True) # Returns a Plotly Figure object
  .show(renderer="colab")
)
```