# Matplotlib and Google Colab: Using ipympl

Tags: python, matplotlib, google-colaboratory

Whenever I try to plot a figure in a Google Colab notebook using matplotlib, a plot is displayed whenever I use `%matplotlib inline` but is not displayed when I do `%matplotlib ipympl` or `%matplotlib widget`. How can I resolve this issue. My goal is to get the plot to be interactive.

> Clarification: when I run `%matplotlib --list` I get the following output
>
> `Available matplotlib backends: ['tk', 'gtk', 'gtk3', 'wx', 'qt4', 'qt5', 'qt', 'osx', 'nbagg', 'notebook', 'agg', 'inline', 'ipympl', 'widget']`

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Also, I have looked at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52859983/interactive-matplotlib-figures-in-google-colab. None of the solutions here worked for me.

Comment: Do you have any indication that google colab actually supports this [jupyter-matplotlib](https://github.com/matplotlib/jupyter-matplotlib) backend? I would think that this is not the case, because it is explicitely written with jupyter in mind.

Comment: Yes, I clarified above

Comment: Oh, that list is not changed by colab. See also https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/15161. I mean you can always ask at colab if they plan to support this anytime soon.

Answer (score 1):

Facing the same issue, I could not get `ipympl` to work with Colab. However, since you mentioned that "*My goal is to get the plot to be interactive*", the next best solution is to use Plotly.

Please see this [shared Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1uVAuE_s6-tqM4E1B4aCiO1NtHyQgyF_m?usp=sharing) for a minimum example.

Python code also copied below for quick reference:

```
!pip install plotly

import plotly.express as px

SHEET_ID = '153pKW5IZRHwx9mLu_uU-hDSK0D3R19vR71EcgMYHn3I'

df = pd.read_csv('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + SHEET_ID + '/export?format=csv')

fig = px.scatter(data_frame=df, x="x", y="y", width=1000, height=800)
fig.show()
```

Answer (score -1):

Available matplotlib backends: ['tk', 'gtk', 'gtk3', 'wx', 'qt4', 'qt5', 'qt', 'osx', 'nbagg', 'notebook', 'agg', 'inline', 'ipympl', 'widget']

Comment: Please add more info and sources