# matplotlib plotting is not working in google colab

Tags: python, matplotlib, google-colaboratory

I wanted to use matplotlib in colab but it didn't work. As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52859983/interactive-matplotlib-figures-in-google-colab) link says I tried both `%matplotlib inline` and `%matplotlib notebook` but they both didn't work. But can I ask why [this link](https://colab.research.google.com/github/jakevdp/PythonDataScienceHandbook/blob/master/notebooks/04.00-Introduction-To-Matplotlib.ipynb#scrollTo=eCo1lGY4UdF2) plots are working well? It seems it's just using normal matplotlib with `%matplotlib inline`. I want to know the difference.

Answer (score 7):

According to `colab` docs:

In the IPython notebook, you also have the option of embedding graphics directly in the notebook, with two possible options:

`%matplotlib notebook` will lead to interactive plots embedded within the notebook.

`%matplotlib inline` will lead to static images of your plot embedded in the notebook.

Comment: I wrote some more detail to the question. Please read again.

Comment: Scroll to LEONARDO PEREIRA RODRIGUES's answer. I had the exact same issue and it fixed it for me!  Other sources had been telling me to "Start by launching the IPython interpreter by typing 'ipython' on the command-line". You can't access the command line in colab without a paid subscription.

Answer (score 4):

I came up with the same problem with Google colab today, the solution is quite simple:
Using `%matplotlib inline`

Here is my code:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

X = np.linspace(-0.1, 10, 20)
y = 2 * X - 1
plt.scatter(X, y)
```

Answer (score 3):

Selecting a GPU from the hardware accelaration tab solved the issue for me.

Go into Edit > Notebook Settings > Select GPU in the drop-down.

Comment: This doesn't work for me

Comment: This worked for me - weird.  I flipped back to CPU, and it retained the inline rendering in Colab.

Answer (score 2):

Plotting from an IPython notebook

The IPython notebook is a browser-based interactive data analysis tool that can combine narrative, code, graphics, HTML elements, and much more into a single executable document.

Plotting interactively within an IPython notebook can be done with the %matplotlib command, and works in a similar way to the IPython shell. In the IPython notebook, you also have the option of embedding graphics directly in the notebook, with two possible options:

- `%matplotlib notebook` will lead to interactive plots embedded within the notebook
- `%matplotlib inline` will lead to static images of your plot embedded in the notebook

Comment: I tried both but they didn't work. My question is why, nonetheless, that [this link](https://colab.research.google.com/github/jakevdp/PythonDataScienceHandbook/blob/master/notebooks/04.00-Introduction-To-Matplotlib.ipynb#scrollTo=eCo1lGY4UdF2) plots are working correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I saw in some issue in github this soluction, and this solved my problem:

```
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"
```

https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3523

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem to the original author -- no matter what I tried, I could not get plots to display in a notebook, even though plots were displayed just fine in other notebooks. I found this very surprising.

I added a dead-simple test plot to the original notebook and to a brand new notebook, and this simple plot did not show up in a factory reset environment of the original notebook, while it was rendered without issue in a new notebook:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
plt.show()
```

Factory resetting the runtime, restarting the browser, and restarting the computer had no impact on this issue over the course of multiple days.

In the end, I found that **closing the browser tab with the notebook, opening a new tab and browsing to colab, and selecting my notebook from the list of files resolved the issue**. This was in Firefox running on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

`%matplotlib notebook` not working in google colab, Use instead `%matplotlib inline`

[image]