# How can I make a matplotlib plot in Google Colab interactive?

Tags: python, matplotlib, google-colaboratory, matplotlib-3d

I am using Python and matplotlib and I am trying to create an interactive plot in Google Colab. I can produce the plot but it is static. My current code is below:

```py
%matplotlib notebook
%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'retina'
from __future__ import print_function, division
import sys
import numpy as np
import astropy.units as u
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
%matplotlib inline
import json
import glob
import shutil
import math
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
```

```py
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

p_r = 299.9032078
p_de = 20.80420061
p_di = 1.5

ax.scatter(p_di,p_r,p_de, s=200, color='b',marker='o')

sta_r = [297.9021920849609,295.904451838485,295.9023343973089,297.90309565270053,296.90333856407784]
sta_de = [20.844424295419174,20.81360810319505,20.723442484679984,20.824023603726815,20.70437024345076]
sta_pa = [-0.5158962093235283,0.7968902494174,0.5119758027825232,-0.6155926470014295,1.2453997167305746]
sta_di = [1/sp for sp in sta_pa]

ax.scatter(sta_di,sta_r,sta_de, s=200, color='darkorange',marker='o')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 18):

You should remove `%matplotlib inline`, which makes the plot static. The `%matplotlib notebook` magic command you put earlier is the one you need for interactive plots.

**Edit:** Colab is only supporting `%matplotlib inline`, [see here](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/616#issuecomment-506829877), and thus **there is no way to get interactive matplotlib plots**.
Yet, if you switch to another environment ([Jupyter or JupyterLab](https://jupyter.org/)), make sure to use `%matplotlib notebook`. On the other side, interactive [plotly](https://plotly.com/) seems to work: [Interactive matplotlib figures in Google Colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52859983/interactive-matplotlib-figures-in-google-colab)

Comment: If I remove the `%matplotlib inline` them my plot doesn't appear at all.

Comment: It seems like Colab is at the moment only supporting `%matplotlib inline`: https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/616#issuecomment-506829877