# Generate interactive plot using mne package in google colab

Tags: python, plot, interactive, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to use mne package to generate interactive plots of EEG data. But it doesn't work on Google Colab. It gives me 2 exact the same static plots instead. Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

As far as I know, Google Colab currently does not allow using `%matplotlib notebook` as a backend. Typically, one uses `%matplotlib notebook` for intercativity while making `matplotlib` plots. It appears that the package you are using makes use of `matplotlib` for visualizations. So, for now, you are out of luck!

You will have use other libraries: [**`altair`**](http://altair-viz.github.io/), [**`plotly`**](https://plotly.com/python/), [**`bokeh`**](https://bokeh.org/), etc. to achieve interactivity on Colab.

See this colab notebook: [Charting in Colaboratory](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/charts.ipynb#scrollTo=ZdEG-d4g4U6v). There are detailed examples for various visualization packages to get you started in the colab-notebook.

### Sample Altair Code for Interactive Plot on Colab

> [Altair](http://altair-viz.github.io/) is a declarative visualization library for creating interactive visualizations in Python, and is installed and enabled in Colab by default.

For example, here is an interactive scatter plot:

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data
cars = data.cars()

alt.Chart(cars).mark_point().encode(
    x='Horsepower',
    y='Miles_per_Gallon',
    color='Origin',
).interactive()
```

[image]

### References

I would recommend you to take a look at the following resources as well.

1. [Charting in Colaboratory - *colab-notebook-example*](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/charts.ipynb#scrollTo=ZdEG-d4g4U6v)
2. [Interactive matplotlib figures in Google Colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52859983/interactive-matplotlib-figures-in-google-colab)