# using plotly in offline mode in google colab

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, google-colaboratory

As per the question, I'm trying to plot a simple figure using plotly in google colab, but I get a blank figure instead. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47230817/plotly-notebook-mode-with-google-colaboratory/47230966) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028965/how-to-display-plotly-outputs-in-google-collaboratory-notebooks) and didn't work.

This is my code:

Cell1

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from  plotly.offline import iplot, init_notebook_mode, plot
import numpy as np

def configure_plotly_browser_state():
  import IPython
  display(IPython.core.display.HTML('''
        <script src="/static/components/requirejs/require.js"></script>
        <script>
          requirejs.config({
            paths: {
              base: '/static/base',
              plotly: 'https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js?noext',
            },
          });
        </script>
        '''))
```

Cell2

```
x = np.arange(10)
y = np.random.random(10) * 3 + x

trace = go.Scatter(x=x, y=y)
configure_plotly_browser_state()
init_notebook_mode(connected=False)
iplot([trace])
```

**EDIT**: Issue solved in version 4.0.0

Comment: I've updated the main answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47230817/plotly-notebook-mode-with-google-colaboratory to include the simple version 4 flow for this.

Comment: Thanks. How do I update to version 4? `pip install plotly --upgrade` updates to 3.6.1

Comment: Try `pip install plotly==4.0.0`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plotly notebook mode with google colaboratory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47230817/plotly-notebook-mode-with-google-colaboratory)

Comment: Done, it worked. I'm closing the question