# Cufflinks shows blank

Tags: python, plotly, cufflinks

I tried importing the financial data and use the following code.
It runs fine but plotly just show blank canvas.
I narrowed down and found out that the problem is cufflink because iplot alone (not using with dataframe still work fine)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EpWG.png)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
%matplotlib inline

start = datetime.datetime(2006, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 1)
# Bank of America
BAC = data.DataReader("BAC", 'yahoo', start, end)

# CitiGroup
C = data.DataReader("C", 'yahoo', start, end)

# Goldman Sachs
GS = data.DataReader("GS", 'yahoo', start, end)

# JPMorgan Chase
JPM = data.DataReader("JPM", 'yahoo', start, end)

# Morgan Stanley
MS = data.DataReader("MS", 'yahoo', start, end)

# Wells Fargo
WFC = data.DataReader("WFC", 'yahoo', start, end)

df = data.DataReader(['BAC', 'C', 'GS', 'JPM', 'MS', 'WFC'],'yahoo', start, end)

tickers = ['BAC', 'C', 'GS', 'JPM', 'MS', 'WFC']

bank_stocks = pd.concat([BAC, C, GS, JPM, MS, WFC],axis=1,keys=tickers)

# Optional Plotly Method Imports
import plotly
import cufflinks as cf
cf.go_offline()

bank_stocks.xs(key='Close',axis=1,level='Stock Info').iplot()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the graph did not show up because the name of the multi-index was missing. Please add the following code before the code to draw the graph.

```
bank_stocks.columns.names = ['Bank Ticker','Stock Info']
```

[image]

Also, it is possible to add the following code as the cause of the missing display. This function needs to be called before executing iplot().See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028965/how-to-display-plotly-outputs-in-google-collaboratory-notebooks/54644249).

```
def enable_plotly_in_cell():
    import IPython
    from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode
    display(IPython.core.display.HTML('''
            <script src="/static/components/requirejs/require.js"></script>
    '''))
    init_notebook_mode( connected=False )

import plotly
import cufflinks as cf
cf.go_offline()
enable_plotly_in_cell()

bank_stocks.xs(key='Close', axis=1, level='Stock Info').iplot()
```

Comment: Thank you. The function enable_plotly_in_cell does help