# Plotly: Why will px.line not show this figure in google colab?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plotly, google-colaboratory

I want to plot an interactive plot for dataset `df`:

```
Time    Temperature
8:23:04     18.5
8:23:04     19
9:12:57     19
9:12:57     20
9:12:58     20
9:12:58     21
9:12:59     21
9:12:59     23
9:13:00     23
9:13:00     25
9:13:01     25
9:13:01     27
9:13:02     27
9:13:02     28
9:13:03     28
```

with code below:

```
import plotly.express as px
df = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/df.csv', sep=',')

fig = px.line(df, x=df["Time"], y=df["Temperature"])
fig.show()
```

but nothing was returned. Why is that? Thanks.

---

**Update:**

Tried code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\\s+')
fig = px.line(df, x=df["Time"], y=df["Temperature"])
fig.show()
```

and incurred error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PyperclipException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-abd6d217e76d> in <module>()
      3 import plotly.express as px
      4 
----> 5 df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\\s+')
      6 fig = px.line(df, x=df["Time"], y=df["Temperature"])
      7 fig.show()

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/clipboard/clipboards.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    122     class ClipboardUnavailable:
    123         def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 124             raise PyperclipException(EXCEPT_MSG)
    125 
    126         def __bool__(self):

PyperclipException: 
    Pyperclip could not find a copy/paste mechanism for your system.
    For more information, please visit https://pyperclip.readthedocs.org
```

Running Approach 2:
[image]

Comment: This only works if you ***copy the data from the sample you provided***! This is not relevant otherwise. Try approach 2 then and see if that works

Comment: @vestland The result is the same using your sample code, I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has to be related to your data import ***or*** plotly itself. I'm getting this plot using two different approaches:

[image]

**Approach 1:**

Copy your dataset using `ctrl+c` and the run this code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\\s+')
fig = px.line(df, x=df["Time"], y=df["Temperature"])
fig.show()
```

**Approach 2:**

I'm importing your data the same way as above, but I'm constructin a dictionary out of the dataframe using `pd.to_dict()` and then I construct a dataframe `df_d` out of that dictionary:

```
import pandas as pd 
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

df_d = pd.DataFrame({'Time': {0: '8:23:04',
                              1: '8:23:04',
                              2: '9:12:57',
                              3: '9:12:57',
                              4: '9:12:58',
                              5: '9:12:58',
                              6: '9:12:59',
                              7: '9:12:59',
                              8: '9:13:00',
                              9: '9:13:00',
                              10: '9:13:01',
                              11: '9:13:01',
                              12: '9:13:02',
                              13: '9:13:02',
                              14: '9:13:03'},
                             'Temperature': {0: 18.5,
                              1: 19.0,
                              2: 19.0,
                              3: 20.0,
                              4: 20.0,
                              5: 21.0,
                              6: 21.0,
                              7: 23.0,
                              8: 23.0,
                              9: 25.0,
                              10: 25.0,
                              11: 27.0,
                              12: 27.0,
                              13: 28.0,
                              14: 28.0}})

#fig = px.line(df, x=df["Time"], y=df["Temperature"])
fig2 =  px.line(df_d, x=df["Time"], y=df_d["Temperature"])

fig2.show()
```

**Conclusion:**

If you're able to produce *any* other plots using `px.express` then the problem has to be related to the way you're importing your data from your csv file. If you're by any chance trying to produce your plots in jupyter lab or in a jupyter notebook, then the problem might be caused by a missing plotly extension in jupyter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried Approach 1 and incurred some error(which is shown in the question). And Approach 2 seems to have the same issue as my previous approach, where the output section is blank but no error is returned.

Comment: @nilsinelabore *Where* are you running this?

Comment: I'm running it on google colab

Comment: @nilsinelabore That is ***very*** essential information, and should be included both in the title and the question itself.

Comment: @nilsinelabore So, as I asked in my first answer, are you able to produce ***any*** plotly figures? Or are you just having issues with this particular case?

Comment: I just realised that it does not work for any plot..

Comment: @nielsinelabore Then the issue boils down to how you can produce plotly figures in google colab. A similar question has been asked and answered here: [Plotly notebook mode with google colaboratory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47230817/plotly-notebook-mode-with-google-colaboratory)

Comment: @nilsinelabore Take a look at the suggestion from the developers there. If those suggestions do not work, please consider adding comments there or asking a new question. I hope it works out for you in the end!

Comment: It did. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

check if your dataset is in correct Csv format and the path is correct: (check if there is a space between time and temperature)

```
Time,Temperature
08:23:04 AM,18.5
08:23:04 AM,19
09:12:57 AM,19
09:12:57 AM,20
09:12:58 AM,20
09:12:58 AM,21
09:12:59 AM,21
09:12:59 AM,23
09:13:00 AM,23
09:13:00 AM,25
09:13:01 AM,25
09:13:01 AM,27
09:13:02 AM,27
09:13:02 AM,28
09:13:03 AM,28
```

a graph will be opened in your browser tab with your graph

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems the format is correct. I can plot the graph using Matplotlib.