# Plotly Map not showing in Colab

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to plot the KSA map through plotly using Google Colab, no error but the map is not shown. Any advice would be appreciated, here is the code

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.offline as py_offline
import plotly.graph_objs as go
py_offline.init_notebook_mode()
import pandas as pd
cases = []
cases.append(go.Scattergeo(
    lon = [46.720798, 46.739295],
    lat = [24.694691, 24.703821],
    text = [0.242, 0.285]
) )

layout = go.Layout(
    title="Saudi Arabia",
    geo = dict(
        resolution = 50,
        scope = 'asia',
        showframe = False,
        showcoastlines = True,
        showland = True,
        landcolor = "rgb(229, 229, 229)",
        countrycolor = "rgb(255, 255, 255)" ,
        coastlinecolor = "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
        projection = dict(
            type = 'mercator',
            scale=3
        ),
        center = dict(
            lon=46,
            lat=24
        )
    )
)

fig = go.Figure(layout=layout, data=cases)
py_offline.iplot(fig, validate=False, filename='Saudi Arabia')
```

Comment: Hi, does this solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47230817/plotly-notebook-mode-with-google-colaboratory

Comment: Thank you, Worked by : fig.show(renderer="colab")