# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'iplot'

Tags: python, dataframe, plot

Can I solve the following error:
'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'iplot'?
I have to create box plot of every Category of my dataset imported form a csv file with pd.read_csv:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv(myfile)
dataset[columns].iplot(kind='box')
```

Comment: Please add more details, including the code you are using and a sample of your dataset.

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: Edit the question to have some sample data that it's your `myfile`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pandas dataframe object does not have the `iplot` method when it isn't linked to plotly. We need [`cufflinks`](https://plot.ly/python/v3/ipython-notebooks/cufflinks/) to link pandas to plotly and add the `iplot` method:

```py
import cufflinks as cf
cf.go_offline()
cf.set_config_file(offline=False, world_readable=True)
```

After this, try plotting directly from the dataframe:

```py
dataset["columns"].iplot(kind="box")
```

Install cufflinks with : `pip install cufflinks --upgrade`)

Comment: iplot error went away after implementing your solution whereas I don't see any plotting in my Jupiter notebook even though the cell runs correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For those facing a similar problem while trying this out in "Google Colab" ( or not getting any image displayed in Google Colab )

From : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47230966/4106458
and combining this with the `asFigure` parameter mentioned in the help message of `iplot` at : https://github.com/santosjorge/cufflinks/blob/master/Cufflinks%20Tutorial%20-%20Plotly.ipynb

We can use the following code to render interactive Plotly graphs on Google Colab

```
import cufflinks as cf
(dataset[column]
  .iplot(kind="box", asFigure=True) # Returns a Plotly Figure object
  .show(renderer="colab")
)
```