# plotly does not show the plots in google colaboratory

Tags: python, pandas, plot, plotly, scatter-plot

I have a dataframe named "Actuals", indexed by time. This is how I want to plot the Load column.

```
fig = go.Figure([go.Scatter(x=Actuals.index, y= Actuals['Load (kW)'])])
fig.show()
```

When I run this part, it executes without rising any error. but it doesn't display the figure. What is the issue and how can I resolve it?
I am using Google colaboratory

Comment: @Yefet, the posts mentions that there is no error.

Comment: @HoOman, this might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47230817/plotly-notebook-mode-with-google-colaboratory

Comment: dear @zabop the post you sent me was right

Answer (score 0):

I should have added this line of code:

```
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default = 'colab'
```