# How to plot yearly data using plotly?

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to plot yearly count of values in plotly, however I am getting unnecessary xticks.  My plotly plot looks like:
[image]

However, I want something like this:
[image]

That extra, xticks is something I don't want.
My plotly code looks like:

```
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x = data.year.value_counts().index.tolist(),
                     y = data.year.value_counts().values.tolist(),
              
    marker_color='#330C73',
    opacity=0.75))
fig.update_xaxes(tickmode = 'array')
fig.update_layout(bargap=0.2, # gap between bars of adjacent location coordinates
    #bargroupgap=0.1, # gap between bars of the same location coordinates,
      title={
        'text': "Yearly Enrolment",
        'y':0.95,
        'x':0.5,
        'xanchor': 'center',
        'yanchor': 'top'},
      xaxis_title="Year",
      yaxis_title="Count",
      font=dict(
          family="Arial",
          size=10
      ),margin=go.layout.Margin(
        l=0, #left margin
        r=0, #right margin
        b=0, #bottom margin
        t=20.5  #top margin
    ),
      width=500,
      height=350,
      legend=dict(orientation="h", font=dict(size=8)),
      paper_bgcolor='rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
      plot_bgcolor='rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)')
fig.show()
```

Comment: Please share the code for your plotly plot to help us help you! Or look at sharing a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Sparrow0hawk added the code in my question

Comment: What are your data types? Execute `data.dtypes`

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"

data = pd.DataFrame({"year":np.random.choice([2019, 2020, 2021], 50)})

fig = data["year"].value_counts().plot(
   kind="bar", 
   title="Yearly SME Enrolment",
   color=["r", "b", "g"],
   labels={"value": "Count",
           "index": "Year",
           # "color": "Year"
        },
)

fig.update_layout(showlegend=False)
fig.show()
```

### Result

[image]

Comment: I am getting the following error "Could not find plotting backend 'plotly'. Ensure that you've installed the package providing the 'plotly' entrypoint, or that the package has a top-level `.plot` method"

Comment: That is because `plotly` is not installed on your environment. Try install it.

Comment: It is installed, I am using plotly 4.9.

Comment: Are you using Jupyter? See this too https://plotly.com/python/pandas-backend/

Comment: I am using colab.

Comment: Can you try and see if any of this work? I am not a Colab user https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47230817/plotly-notebook-mode-with-google-colaboratory